# Meteor send to active users

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor, meteorite

I starting with writing a meteorjs webpage. I started with the leaderboard example. This works great. I added some new functions. I added a jquery notification script. (Noty http://ned.im/noty/ )

When I give a person five points a activate the Noty plugin by using this code

```
var n = noty({text: txt,timeout: 2000});
......
Template.leaderboard.events({
    'click input.inc': function () {
      Players.update(Session.get("selected_player"), {$inc: {score: 5}});
      notje("Er heeft iemand een score gegeven");
      Method.call("callHouse");
    },
```

The notification will only displayed to my browser and not to other users. How can i use a notification to all active users.
Users -> Server -> All users

I hope you can help me with this issue

Comment: In server side `Meteor.users.find({})` will give you the all logged-in users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to create a notifications collection (client & server):

```
notifications = new Meteor.Collection("notifications");
```

Then insert your message in there and display it using an observe handle. Make sure you add something which is user specific so that you can use a smaller subset of users. And also identify when its used and mark them as ready so they're no longer published and the user doesn't keep receiving them.

Then you could do something like this on your client side:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    notifications.find().observe({
        added: function(doc) {
            //Message can be contained in doc.txt

            //Not sure if this bit is right, but basically trigger the notification:
            n = noty({text: doc.txt,timeout: 2000});
        }
    });
});
```

Hopefully this gives you a bit of a rough idea on how to do it.

Comment: Wouw thank you for your reply. How do I activate the collection: Like this...
notifications.added(text("Er heeft iemand een score gegeven"));

Comment: What do you want that to do? But yes you could write your own `text` method to do this provided you still use the observer.